# Video file codec cant play normally. Starting 3rd second Sound mutes and unmutes every few exact seconds

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, media-player

Strange file cant play normally. Sound jumps up and down after playing 3sec. Whats problem with theese files? They work normally only after converting. Im using Handbrake program for that. If open with VLC then all filetypes work except theese 2 have strange sound playback. What settings in VLC i need to change to make it playable without converting?

http://failiem.lv/u/vhemgmb

http://failiem.lv/u/rzmojuk